# Converting a Java Applet to an Application

Tags: java, applet

I know this question has been answered elsewhere, but none of them seem to work. I don't know if the solution is different depending on the code, but that's what I'm guessing. Anyway, all I want to do is take this simple Applet (a Pong game) and change it to an Application. That's possible right? Thank you in advance! :)

```
package net.laserball.src;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class LaserBallMain extends JApplet 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 400;
public static final int HEIGHT = 400;

private PaintSurface canvas;

public void init()
{
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    canvas = new PaintSurface();
    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = 
        new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new AnimationThread(this), 
        0L, 20L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
}

class AnimationThread implements Runnable
{
JApplet c;

public AnimationThread(JApplet c)
{
    this.c = c;
}

public void run()
{
    c.repaint();
}
}

class PaintSurface extends JComponent
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int paddle_x = 0;
int paddle_y = 360;

int score = 0;

float english = 1.0F;

Ball ball;

Color[] color = {Color.RED, Color.ORANGE,
                 Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE,
                 Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE};

int colorIndex;

public PaintSurface()
{
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getX() - 30 - paddle_x > 5)
                english = -1.5F;
            else if (e.getX() - 30 - paddle_x < -5)
                english = -1.5F;
            else
                english = 1.0F;
            paddle_x = e.getX() - 30;
        }
    });

    ball = new Ball(20);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    Shape paddle = new Rectangle2D.Float(
        paddle_x, paddle_y, 60, 8);

    g2.setColor(color[colorIndex % 6]);

    if(ball.intersects(paddle_x, paddle_y, 60, 8)
        && ball.y_speed > 0)
    {
        ball.y_speed = -ball.y_speed;
        ball.x_speed = (int)(ball.x_speed * english);
        if(english != 1.0F)
            colorIndex++;
        score += Math.abs(ball.x_speed * 10);
    }

    if(ball.getY() + ball.getHeight()
        >= LaserBallMain.HEIGHT)
    {
        ball = new Ball(20);
        score -= 1000;
        colorIndex = 0;
    }

    ball.move();
    g2.fill(ball);

    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fill(paddle);

    g2.drawString("Score: " + score, 250, 20);
}
}

class Ball extends Ellipse2D.Float
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public int x_speed, y_speed;
private int d;
private int width = LaserBallMain.WIDTH;
private int height = LaserBallMain.HEIGHT;

public Ball(int diameter)
{
    super((int)(Math.random() * (LaserBallMain.WIDTH - 20) + 1),
        0, diameter, diameter);
    this.d = diameter;
    this.x_speed = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 5);
    this.y_speed = (int)(Math.random() * 5 + 5);
}

public void move()
{
    if(super.x < 0 || super.x > width - d)
        x_speed = -x_speed;
    if(super.y < 0 || super.y > height - d)
        y_speed = -y_speed;
    super.x += x_speed;
    super.y += y_speed;     
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LaserBallMain laserBallMain = new LaserBallMain();

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
frame.add(laserBallMain);

// Set frame size and other properties
...

// Call applet methods
laserBallMain.init();
laserBallMain.start();

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, both of you! :D seeing the code helped me better. Now I can continue my little project :)

Answer (score 2):

- Create a new class called something like `Main`
- Create method within `Main` called `public static void main(String args[])`
- Within the `main` method use `EventQueue.invokeLater` and pass it a `Runnable` to execute the initial program logic within the Event Dispatching Thread...

For example...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    }
});
```

- Within the run method, create a new instance of a `JFrame`.
- Place the logic from the original `init` method within the `run` method as well, but instead of adding `canvas` to the applet, add it to the frame (you created in the previous step).

You will probably need to override `getPreferredSize` of the `PaintSurface` class, returning an appropriate size of the game surface.

You should also take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and you might find [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) interesting as well.

Personally, I would move the entire program logic to some other class, may be a `JPanel` for example, then you would only need to add this component to whatever container you wanted

Comment: So this is in a seperate class file? What do I do with all the rest of the code in the original class? Sorry, I'm just having trouble understanding.

Comment: Could you show me a setup of any kind? Edit the code I posted maybe?

Comment: Start with a plain class, create `JFrame`.  This will act as the container instead of `JApplet`